# Symfony2 security different firewalls don't redirect properly to login

Tags: security, symfony, redirect

I configured 3 secured areas based on the user type: admin, teacher and student. When I'm accessing /admin, I'm redirected properly to /admin/login. But when I'm accessing /teacher or /student the redirection fails, although I'm being redirected to /teacher/login or /student/login I'm getting this error:

**The page isn't redirecting properly**
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

This is my security.yml:

```
    firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    admin:
         pattern: ^/admin
         form_login:
             check_path: login_check
             login_path: /admin/login
             provider: chain_provider
             csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
             default_target_path: /admin
         logout:       true
    teacher:
         pattern: ^/teacher
         form_login:
             check_path: login_check
             login_path: /teacher/login
             provider: chain_provider
             csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
             default_target_path: /teacher
         logout:       true
    student:
         pattern: ^/student
         form_login:
             check_path: login_check
             login_path: /student/login
             provider: chain_provider
             csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
             default_target_path: /student
         logout:       true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/teacher/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/teacher/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/student/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/student/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/teacher, role: ROLE_TEACHER }
    - { path: ^/student, role: ROLE_USER }
```

I need some help. What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've secured your login forms ... so when Symfony tries to redirect to your login form, it tries to redirect to your login form, tries to redirect to your login form, tries to redirect ...

Try this:

```
admin_login:
    pattern:                 ^/admin/login
    anonymous:               ~

admin:
    pattern:                 ^/admin
    form_login:
        login_path:          /admin/login
        check_path:          /login_check
        provider:            chain_provider
        csrf_provider:       form.csrf_provider
        default_target_path: /admin
    logout:
        path:                /logout
        target:              /admin/login

teacher_login:
    pattern:                 ^/teacher/login
    anonymous:               ~

teacher:
    pattern:                 ^/teacher
    form_login:
       ... etc ...

student_login:
    pattern:                 ^/student/login
    anonymous:               ~

student:
    pattern:                 ^/student
    form_login:
        .... etc ...

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login$,   roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/teacher/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/student/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    ...
    - { path: ^/admin,          roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/teacher,        roles: ROLE_TEACHER }
    - { path: ^/student,        roles: ROLE_USER }
```

This is covered under the heading [Avoid Common Pitfalls](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html#avoid-common-pitfalls) in the Symfony Cookbook.

**THE ORDER OF YOUR FIREWALLS IS IMPORTANT**

Note that the 'login firewalls' are defined ahead of their partner firewalls.

Note also that I added a '/' to the front of your check_path to remind you that you need to define a route for it.  If you use annotations to define your routes, you'll need to create an empty action method in a controller somewhere so that the router has something to chew on.

Your 'logout' definitions look suspect to me as well.  Not saying they're completely incorrect - just that I've never seen them defined that way before and am not exactly certain how your definitions would work given what I know of Symfony.

In the case of the '/logout' paths I've defined in the example above, you would - again - need to create a valid route for these ... even though Symfony won't actually execute any 'logout' method you define in your controllers.

The logout stuff is covered [HERE](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#logging-out)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I added `anonymous: ~` below every firewall and I'm redirected correctly now. But after entering username/password I'm geting this message. **You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration.**

Comment: Just to be sure ... you can't just add anonymous below each firewall - you need to set each login path up under its own firewall - and the order is important.  admin_login: needs to come before admin:, etc ...  You also need to make sure that you configure routes for your login_check path.  If you have used annotations to define your routes, this means you need to create an empty action method in a controller so that the router has something to chew on.  I'll make a quick edit to my answer ...